# Access form: intermittent Run-time error 424

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error

I’ve got a form for user to add records by clicking on a button.
Some users have encountered the 424 error upon clicking the button, intermittently - not all the time.

When debugged, it highlighted the first row of the code (in bold) - what could be wrong tho?

This error handling code is found in the onclick event of the button.

```
Err1:
**Description.setfocus**
Add.enabled=false
Msg ox (err.description)
```

Comment: Why is MsgBox missing `B`? What is exact message of error 424? What is Description - a textbox?

Comment: Hi June7! 
MsgBox was a typo. The exact msg is - runtime error ‘424’. Object Required. The description is a button, an add record button

Comment: Try renaming your controls - `Description` and `Add` are both reserved words in Access.

Comment: And what button is clicked? If it is Description then it already has focus. I cannot replicate issue. Perhaps need to post complete procedure. Description and Add as names work fine but I agree, should avoid using reserved words as names. I like to use prefixes like: btnDescription.

Comment: Can you please try this `Me.[Description].setfocus`?

Answer (score 0):

Understanding you are at a Form module, replace

```
Description.setfocus
```

With

```
Me!Description.setfocus
```